# What might cause a low-level mouse hook to miss button-up events?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, setwindowshookex

I wrote a simple program to print all mouse events to the debug view:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>


HHOOK g_mouseEventHook = NULL;


LRESULT CALLBACK mouseEventHookProc( int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    if ( code != HC_ACTION ) {
        return ::CallNextHookEx( g_mouseEventHook, code, wParam, lParam );
    }

    PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT mi = (PMSLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;

    char buf[2048];
    sprintf( buf, __FUNCTION__": caught event: wparam = 0x%08x, time = %d, x = %d, y = %d", wParam, mi->time, mi->pt.x, mi->pt.y );
    OutputDebugStringA( buf );

    return ::CallNextHookEx( g_mouseEventHook, code, wParam, lParam );
}


int main()
{
    g_mouseEventHook = ::SetWindowsHookEx( WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseEventHookProc, ::GetModuleHandle( NULL ), 0 );

    MSG msg;
    while ( ::GetMessage( &msg, NULL, 0, 0 ) > 0 ) {
        ::TranslateMessage( &msg );
        ::DispatchMessage( &msg );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code doesn't bother cleaning up (e.g. unregistering hooks or exiting the message loop cleanly); you just Ctrl+C to abort it.

I compiled this using Visual Studio 2013 by running

```
cl main.cpp user32.lib
```

When running it, the debugger output shows (visible using e.g. [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview)) this output for a 'slow' click in which I press the left mouse button, wait a moment, and then release the left mouse button:

```
[1660] mouseEventHookProc: caught event: wparam = 0x00000201, time = 17367092, x = 546, y = 90
[1660] mouseEventHookProc: caught event: wparam = 0x00000200, time = 17367092, x = 546, y = 90
[1660] mouseEventHookProc: caught event: wparam = 0x00000202, time = 17368636, x = 546, y = 90
[1660] mouseEventHookProc: caught event: wparam = 0x00000200, time = 17368636, x = 546, y = 90
```

The `wparam` value corresponds to standard Window messages:

- 0x0200 => [`WM_MOUSEMOVE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645616(v=vs.85).aspx)
- 0x0201 => [`WM_LBUTTONDOWN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607(v=vs.85).aspx)
- 0x0202 => [`WM_LBUTTONUP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645608(v=vs.85).aspx)

I.e. in the above trace, my program saw a mouse down, mouse move, mouse up, mouse move. It appears each button event always goes with a move event to the same coordinate (and with the same time stamp).

When clicking a little faster, as I would do normally, the 'up' event is often dropped though. I.e. the debug trace looks like this:

```
[1660] mouseEventHookProc: caught event: wparam = 0x00000201, time = 17371038, x = 546, y = 90
[1660] mouseEventHookProc: caught event: wparam = 0x00000200, time = 17371054, x = 546, y = 90
[1660] mouseEventHookProc: caught event: wparam = 0x00000200, time = 17371132, x = 546, y = 90
```

I.e. there is just a mouse down, then two mouse move events. The time stamps are different in all cases, and the up event is missing completely.

I'm doing these experiments in a Windows 7 VM running in VMware Fusion.

Is anyone able to reproduce and/or explain this behaviour? Is there a bug in my test program, or is this some peculiar behaviour of the low-level hooks I'm missing?

Comment: code may be bit not optimal but is correct. guess that something with debugview output. for check exactly - use 4 global or static variables: `static ULONG ld, lu, rd, ru;` and on every call `switch (wParam)
  {
  case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
   ld++;
   break;
  case WM_LBUTTONUP:
   lu++;
   break;
  case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
   rd++;
   break;
  case WM_RBUTTONUP:
   ru++;
   break;
  }` increment corresponded variable. print it all every time, or after you remove hook

Comment: @RbMm Interesting idea - I tried it, but the counters match the DebugView output: there are less 'up' events than 'down' unless I click very slowly.

Comment: in this case dont know what can produce this. i for test now click as fast as i can many times - and got - equal (`ld==lu && `rd==ru`) at the end of test

Comment: Just tried it in MSVC 2017 (running from IDE with an `F5`) - there are no "extra" move events **and** there's always an `up` event for each `down`, slow or fast. I did make a tiny code change though: added a new line at the end of that debug message ;-)

Comment: One thing which just occurred to me was that maybe the fact that I'm working in a virtual machine might influence this (I extended my question accordingly). I'll try this on a real machine.

Comment: @YePhIcK For what it's worth, I just noticed that for me, the missing up events seem to occur about once out of five tries. I.e. I have to click a couple of times to notice this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know of that a hook can miss certain events is if somebody else is in front of you in the hook list and they eat the event by not calling `CallNextHookEx`.

If your hook function is too slow then Windows might unhook you without telling you but that means you get no further events from that HHOOK instance.

A VM might loose the click somewhere between your host machine and the guest machine, especially if you switch between the VM window and other things on your host machine. You could rule this out by creating a little test application that also prints its mouse events and run it in the guest.